# connect to ssh via iptable tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables, nat

there is two server A (1.1.1.1) and B(2.2.2.2)
I defined an iptable PREROUTING like this

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:22
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

despite it seems initial connection to server B set successfully, as it is requesting username and password, but I cant login to IP 1.1.1.1 & port number 1111 in putty
the user is valid and existing user "test" and is able to login directly to server B

```
 login as: test
 test@1.1.1.1's password:
 Access denied
```

Comment: What do you see in the SSH server's logs? Did the hostkey seen at 1.1.1.1 port 1111 exactly match the hostkey seen when directly connecting to 2.2.2.2 port 22?

Comment: i left my office 2 hour ago, and now when i test connection from home it start working!!!!!!!